# See all breakpoints in Visual Studio 2010+

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, breakpoints

Is there a window in Visual Studio 2010 and newer where I can see all the breakpoints that I have in my project or solution?

Comment: Another way is [using the Command Window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77683144/2638227).

Answer (score 433, accepted):

Try **Debug** -> **Windows** -> **Breakpoints**.

Comment: This is not available in Visual C# 2010 Express.

Comment: Yep, because putting it under a consistent entry like : "View-> Breakpoints Window"
is just too consistent of a user interface design, so Microsoft cannot implement it that way.  Every couple of years when I have to reinstall VS2010 due to a computer refresh I need to look this up again. <sigh>

Answer (score 38):

**Default Shortcuts:**

To open the break point window:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd>

If you wanted to delete all breakpoints:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+B by default here. (Possibly due to ReSharper though)

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+B worked for me as well and I have no add ons running. Ctrl+D, B brought up the breakpoint interface for adding a new breakpoint at the current cursor location.

Comment: The comment by @Mike_OBrien works for Visual Studio 2015 and should be an answer, not a comment, or perhaps added on to the answer by MartinLiversage

Comment: In Visual Studio 2017, Ctrl+D duplicates the current selection and Ctrl+B adds a new breakpoint at the current line. Ctrl+F9 does nothing.

Answer (score 21):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Also in VS 2019

Answer (score 9):

Breakpoints window is not included in some Express versions of Visual Studio.

Its included in `Pro`, `Premium`, and `Ultimate`. Here is the manual for the versions : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/02ckd1z7%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
Tools> Settings> Expert Settings
```

Comment: I needed this because I am using express.

Answer (score 2):

C# Express 2010 does not include the command <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>;  The options Tools> Settings> Expert Settings work only if you need more options, but for view all the break points are not incluyed.

Answer (score -2):

To open the Breakpoints Window

On the Debug menu, point to Windows and then choose Breakpoints.

Comment: Why add an answer that is exactly the same as the accepted answer from nearly 2 years prior?