# How can I see all breakpoints in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: breakpoints, visual-studio-2013

I can toggle breakpoints for any line, but I could not see the list of all breakpoints (Breakpoints window).

When I go menu *Debug* → *Windows* → ...  It does not show me *Breakpoints* window.

Am I missing something?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/7781977/1136253

Answer (score 62):

Simply use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>, which should show you the breakpoints window.

Comment: There's no "simply" about it. This is /hard/ to find. The official M$ pages didn't have it readily available. +1

Comment: This doesn't work for me in Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web -- I'm not sure if this is different from Visual Studio Express 2013 preview.

Answer (score 46):

You can select from top menu bar: **Debug -> Windows -> Breakpoints**

Comment: Please read the question carefully. His problem is that he unable to find breakpoints through this path.

Comment: This is the correct answer - he should ware glasses ... ;-)

Comment: The shortcut is `Ctrl + D, B`.  Maybe that will work, even if the menu option is missing (VS 2015).

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2013 I see the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way: First open the *Command Window* using the menu *View > Other Windows > Command Window* or just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>.
Then type and press Enter

```
> bl
```

or

```
> Debug.Breakpoints
```

in the *Command Window* as in the image.

[image]