# Visual Studio 2013 Express web edition break point window

Tags: web, visual-studio-2013, window, breakpoints, visual-studio-express

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Express Web edition and am wondering where the break point window is.

I can place break points, so there must be a break point window to display all the break points easily. I have also tried the short cut CTRL ALT B, yet no window is displayed.

How can I open the break point window in Visual Studio 2013 Express Web edition?

Thanks in advance

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/7781977/1136253

Answer (score 1):

atleast in Visual studio 2008, breakpoint window was not included in express edition. Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/02ckd1z7%28v=vs.90%29.aspx . I couldn't see the same update for 2013..