# How to enable breakpoints of current file only in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2013, breakpoints

For example, I am debugging a project that contains several source files where I already have breakpoints. During debugging I once disabled all the breakpoints from debug menu (`Debug -> Disable All Breakpoints`).

But now I want to enable the breakpoints only of a particular source file which I want to debug. In Visual Studio (2013), how to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [See all breakpoints in Visual Studio 2010+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781977/see-all-breakpoints-in-visual-studio-2010)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the breakpoint window (Debug > Windows > Breakpoints), put your file name in the "Search:" box and select "File" in the "In Column:" drop down.

The Breakpoints window toolbar has a button for "Enable or disable all breakpoints matching the current search criteria"